# Does This Hash Function Collide?

Tags: algorithm, hash, bit-manipulation, radix, gdscript

Context: Apologies for the misuse of "hash function". I'm trying to serialize game state in a compact but plaintext manner -- I can pack most of what I need into one 64-bit int but having the player copy one long string of numbers (up to 20 digits) seemed extravagant. I thought if I could map them to a more information-dense set of characters I could reduce what they'd have to copy/paste.

Original Question:

I'm trying to write a hash function that converts 64-bit ints to shorter strings and vice-versa: I want it to be fully reversible with no collisions.

My thought is that the maximum value of such an int is `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` (20 digits, base 10). If I converted that to base 64 (the radix; not the commonly used encoding scheme!), then I could represent that same value in 13 characters (64 ^ 13 = `302,231,454,903,657,293,676,544`).

I wrote the following functions to convert from radix10 int to radix64 string, but I'm not 100% sure I didn't miss an edge case:

```
const HASH : Array # Contains 64 characters: 0-9, a-z, A-Z, '?', and '!'
const HASH_MASK : int = int(pow(2, 6) - 1)
const HIGH_MASK : int = int(pow(2, 64)) # 0b10000000...

func to_hash(value : int) -> String:
    var string : String = ""
    while true:
        string = HASH[value & HASH_MASK] + string
        # Shift bits without preserving high bit.
        for _i in range(6): # 2 ^ 6 = 64, the number of hash characters available.
            value = (value >> 1) & (~HIGH_MASK)
        if value == 0:
            break
    return string

func from_hash(string : String) -> int:
    var value : int = 0
    for character in string:
        var bits : int = HASH.find(character)
        assert(bits != -1, "Invalid hash character: " + character)
        value = (value << 6) | bits
    return value
```

Does that algorithm have collisions? Or will it meet my use case that every unique int64 produces a unique, uniquely-reversible hash string?

Comment: You do not want a hash function, you want an encryption. That is a one-to-one mapping, while a hash is a many-to-one mapping. Hashes can have collisions; an encryption cannot. That is why you can decrypt a cyphertext to get back the original plaintext. In general, a hash is not reversible.

Comment: Hash functions lose information. Consequently, they are not reversible, and are bound to have collisions. Thus, as the prior comment says, what you want is not a hash. You are looking for some kind of encoding, which might or might not be a cipher. Now, the question you pose is edging on code review. It is not what we usually do here. Have you tested the code? Do you have reason to think it is not wrong? Or is this just speculation? - What I don't trust is the `HASH_MASK` which is not in the code. On a related note, know that GDScript has binary literals.

Comment: Assuming `HASH_MASK` is 0x3f, your `to_mask` code should right-shift `value` by 6 bits at a time, not 1 bit at a time. Also, by my count, you'd only need 11 radix64 characters (11*6=66 bits) to capture all possible 64-bit values. And no, the algorithm has no collisions, but it's not a hash algorithm.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk What would you call this algorithm?

Comment: @hola: In one sense you can call it an injective function or a one-to-one function, in another it's simply an encoding of 64 bits into 66 bits. That's if I understand it correctly, as I noted the code seems a little bit wrong to me.

Comment: @Theraot apologies for the missing `HASH_MASK` constant; added.

The best test I could conceive of was to check `x == from_hash(to_hash(x))` many times, but I can't do that exhaustively.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk bit shifts on negative numbers seemed to preserve the high bit; `& (~HIGH_MASK)` felt like the best way to stop that.

The idea and implementation was all fevered guess-and-check, hence my uncertainty even after testing.

Obviously I was wrong-headed in thinking I was saving bits when converting 12345 to ABC, though I'm still saving printed characters.

I'll update for context.

Comment: @HammerBro. `value = (value >> 6) & 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (that's a number with the 58 low bits set and the 6 high bits clear, which will save you from sign-extension).

Comment: I'm going to say that it doesn't collide, isn't a hash function, and Z85 (https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec/32/) is a better algorithm for my purposes anyway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too specific, too close to a code review, and mostly answered via comments.